# Attach JProfiler to Running Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, jprofiler

When I try to attach JProfiler to a running Eclipse Helios, 3.6 I think, I get

> ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it from happening?

I can attach just fine to a Juno Eclipse instance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's shown in a pop-up in JProfiler. I could try it again if you're interested; I've kind of given up on debugging Eclipse after trying VisualVM, JProfiler, and YourKit. (Do you know of any profiler that can handle it?)

Comment: Instead of attaching, try "Session->Integration Wizards->New remote integration" in JProfiler and pass the VM parameter given by the integration wizard to eclipse when you start it. That is more reliable than attaching.

Comment: @IngoKegel Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It fails to connect. I think because eclipse uses it's own process instead of the Java process.